# Error passing arguments to template function with const qualifier

Tags: c++, templates, constants, qualifiers

I have this code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
void func1(T& value)
{
    std::cout << "passed 1 ..." << std::endl;
}

template <template <typename> class T, typename U>
void func2(T<U>& value)
{
    std::cout << "passed 2 ..." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<int> a;
    const std::auto_ptr<int> ca;

    // case 1: using func1
    func1(a);  // OK
    func1(ca); // OK

    // case 2: using func2
    func2(a);  // OK
    func2(ca); // Compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

In the first case the function 'func1' accepts a generic argument regardless of the qualifier, however the second case the function 'func2' fails when the argument has the const qualifier. Why this happens ?

This is the compilation error:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/Test2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test2.d" -MT"src/Test2.d" -o "src/Test2.o" "../src/Test2.cpp"
../src/Test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/Test2.cpp:27: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::auto_ptr<int>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::auto_ptr<int>’
../src/Test2.cpp:11: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void func2(T<U>&) [with T = std::auto_ptr, U = int]’
make: *** [src/Test2.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Post the exact error please.

Comment: Clang, OTOH, reports a [substitution failure](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f3b5cf491634c3e).

Comment: Ignoring the reason, you can put a `const` to solve the problem: `void func2(const T<U>& value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the case of `func1`, the compiler needs to deduce `T` and we get

- `T` is `std::auto_ptr<int>` in the first call
- `T` is `const std::auto_ptr<int>` in the second call

In both cases `T` is valid in itself.

Now for `func2`, the compiler needs to deduce `T` and `U`, where `T` is a template template parameter. What would be needed is:

- `T` is `std::auto_ptr`, `U` is `int` in the first call
- `T` is `const std::auto_ptr`, `U` is `int` in the second call

and there's your problem: `T` can not be `const std::auto_ptr` itself, as it combined a type-property `const` with a template `std::auto_ptr` which is not a valid type.

Comment: Hi, I understand what you say. But in both functions the compiler needs to deduct "T", in "func1" apparently can be deducted as "const std::auto_ptr" without problems, however you say that in "func2" is not valid. Really the point I want to know is whether this problem is specific to template template arguments in the process of deduction. Thanks

Comment: @hammer You don't really understand what it means. `func1` does *not* deduce `T` to `const std::auto_ptr`, but to `const std::auto_ptr<int>` which is the crucial difference here. You need to distinguish between the template `std::auto_ptr` (which can not by itself be combined with `const`) and the type `std::auto_ptr<int>` which is based on the template and which can be combined with `const`.

Comment: Now I see it all, that was the explanation I needed. Thanks for everything.