# Why does passing a const object to a templated function expecting a non-const template type argument result in a compilation error?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following templated function:

```
template <template<class, class> class V, class T, class Allocator>
void fn(V<T, Allocator>& v)
{
  for (T& t : v) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
  }
}
```

When I pass it a non-`const` vector like:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
fn(v);
```

The compiler is happy, and I am happy. However, when I pass `fn()` a `const` vector like:

```
const std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
fn(v);
```

<strike>All hell breaks loose.</strike>It will result in a compilation error. With GCC 4.9.2, the error message is:

```
 In function 'int main()':
17:7: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::vector<int>&' from expression of type 'const std::vector<int>'
7:6: note: in passing argument 1 of 'void fn(V<T, Allocator>&) [with V = std::vector; T = int; Allocator = std::allocator<int>]'
```

I thought that `V<T, Allocator>&` will be deduced to `const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>&`. However, this is not the case. Why is this so?

Comment: If a function declaration expect a non-const that means it want to mutate it. It make sense the compiler don't allow this. It is a rule of thumb to pass argument as a const reference/pointer if your function don't mutate it.

Comment: The function accepts the argument by non-`const` reference, which means (for the caller) that the function may change its argument.   A `const` object is one that is intended to not be (logically) changed.    Passing an object that is intended to remain unchanged to a function that may change it is invalid - hence the diagnostics in the second case.

Comment: I'm with ^^. And as you're not modifying the objects, you should as well use `for (T const& t : v)`. (And `std::endl` causes a buffer flush, so you can replace that with `'\n'` for better performance).... but it is interesting why the const-qualification of V is dropped...

Comment: This is a dupe of [Error passing arguments to template function with const qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19036424), but I'm not satisfied with the answer there.

Comment: @JHBonarius That's a good dupe. Why don't you like the answer?

Comment: @UltimaWeapon, such behaviour strikes to me as odd. When I'm using a similar templated function, `template <class T> void fn(T& t) { ... }`. and passing it a variable of primitive type, even with `const`, I get no error. I would presume this to be due to differing template deduction rules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error passing arguments to template function with const qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036424/error-passing-arguments-to-template-function-with-const-qualifier)

Comment: @super because it's specifically about `std::auto_ptr`, quote _"there's your problem: `T` can not be `const std::auto_ptr` itself, as it combined a type-property `const` with a template `std::auto_ptr` which is not a valid type"_

Comment: @JHBonarius Uhm. It's not specifically about `std::auto_ptr` at all. It literally says *as it combined a type-property const with a template* in that same line of text... which is the exact same issue as here.

Comment: @super you're right. I now also voted close dupe. at the TS: why are you using gcc 4.9.2? That's over 6 years old! We're at version 10.2, going to 11.0 now.

Comment: @JHBonariusm, since I was just creating an MRE, I decided to use [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh). It just happens that it uses GCC 4.9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that `V<T, Allocator>&` will be deduced to `const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>&`

This would be true if the parameter was plain `U`, like `template<class U> void fn(U&);`.

Type deduction is pattern matching. `const` is part of the type, hence the pattern `U` can be deduced to `T const`. Consider:

```
using T = int const;
T var;

template<class U>
void fn(U&);

fn(var); // -> fn<int const>(int const&);
// We deduce U = T = int const
```

Type aliases are transparent, so we never actually deduce `T`. The `const`ness however is still part of the type of `var`. The compiler then "invents" a new type alias in form of the template parameter, as if:

```
void fn<int const>(int const&)
{
    using U = int const;
    // ...
}
```

---

However, the pattern `V<X>` is a template instantiation, not a any type. In the end, we need to make the function prototype compatible to the call site. So we need to deduce `V` such that we get `void fn(vector<int> const);`. This would only work if we deduce `V` to be a metafunction:

```
template<class U>
using M = vector<U> const;

template<template<class> class V, class T>
void fn(V<T>&);

M<int> var;
fn(var); // ?? fn<M, int>(M<int>);
```

As with type aliases, alias templates are transparent - they're never deduced themselves. The second you write `M<int>` it gets resolved to `vector<int> const` and we forget about the alias template/metafunction being in use.

The compiler could "invent this metafunction" when it sees the pattern `V<T>` and the type `vector<int> const`, but I think this "inventing of the metafunction" is just not supported. Neither is augmentation of metafunctions like `vector const` (without template arguments, to keep it an unapplied metafunction). Metafunctions are not really a thing in the language, we deal with *transparent alias templates* (which are never deduced) and actual *class templates* which don't support the notion of adding/removing `const` (they don't deal with qualifiers, just classes).

If it were supported, it could behave as if:

```
void fn<..>(vector<int> const&)
{
    template<class T>
    using U = vector<T> const;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This might be a result of alias templates coming into play only with C++11... the deduction rules had already been written by that point.